# Selenium Cookie Retrieving Warnings

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

i am using selenium and idle to create and reuse cookies for selenium sicne logging in to some website everytime is a hassle.

sample code i used to save cookies:-

```
from webserver import keep_alive
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pickle

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
time.sleep(120)
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

and after i was able to save cookies in a file i edited the code to retrieve cookies next time i execute

```
from webserver import keep_alive
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pickle

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
time.sleep(5)
for cookie in cookies: 
  driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
```

but it doesnt work as intended giving an error when trying to insert cookies :-

```
main.py:15: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
main.py:19: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
main.py:23: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
main.py:15: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
main.py:19: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
main.py:23: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.get("discord.com/login")
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 436, in get
main.py:15: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
main.py:19: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
main.py:23: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 520, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
main.py:15: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
main.py:19: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
main.py:23: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 520, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
main.py:15: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
main.py:19: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
main.py:23: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1128, in add_cookie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1128, in add_cookie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.get("discord.com/login")
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 436, in get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.get("discord.com/login")
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 436, in get
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```py
driver.get("discord.com/login")
```

You are passing an invalid parameter to the `driver.get` method since `discord.com/login` is not a valid URL.
It should be `https://discord.com/login` as you yourself use it several lines before.

```py
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
```

Comment: even after that the problem with cookie injection is not working idk if its a logical error. i am getting the same error

Comment: OK, what is the error now? I gave my answer according to the error traceback you are presented in the question. In case now it still not working it should be another error

Comment: I edited the question initially according to the new output please look thru it again. thankyou so much

Comment: Well, editing the question is a kind of asking a new question since now it's another error...

Comment: Can you check the following: 1) Validate cookies are saved correctly with the `pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))` code line. 2) `cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))` is giving a list of valid cookies so that `driver.add_cookie(cookie)` line is getting a valid cookie object?

Comment: i am sorry i didnt know how to post the new error otherwise. i am sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: i think the cookies are stored correctly